# decreasing coefficients in R's coefplot?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, coefplot

`coefplot` from `library(coefplot)` has a variable `decreasing` which when set to to `TRUE` the coefficients should be plotted in descending order

But when I run a toy example:

```
data(tips, package = "reshape2")
mod1 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker, data = tips)
coefplot.glm(mod2, decreasing = TRUE)
```

the coefficients aren't in descending order.

What am I missing?

**EDIT** I was missing `sort = "magnitude"`. However, this doesn't work with `multiplot`:

```
data(tips, package = "reshape2")
mod1 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker, data = tips)
mod2 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker + size, data = tips)
multiplot(mod1, mod2, decreasing = TRUE, sort = "magnitude")
```

Comment: @invictus, please add a new question.  Don't make this a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @BenBolker well, based on the highest voted answer in that thread, a slight extension to the question (from `coefplot()` to `multiplot()`) is fair game, but sure, whatever. Only trouble is a user (at least me) can only post once every 90 mins.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi the question came to me out of the blue after reading your answer. I wouldn't call it a great departure from the first question.

Comment: general question: how should sorting in decreasing order work when there's more than one model which might have different coefficient rank orders?  Sort by coefficients of the first model?

Comment: @BenBolker first you demand a new post, then you go commenting on the old post...

Comment: "demand" is a little strong, maybe; "request"?  but OK.  I didn't see the new post.

Comment: "Commenting: it's a milder way to register my disapproval" -Ben Bolker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `sort = "magnitude"`:

```
coefplot(mod1, decreasing = TRUE, sort = "magnitude")
```

[image]

The default sorting is "natural", which is effectively `1:length(coef(mod1))`.

Comment: Awesome. But how is this extended for the `multiplot` case?