# order the coefficients by magnitude in multiplot

Tags: r, coefplot

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197807/decreasing-coefficients-in-rs-coefplot?noredirect=1#comment67661855_40197807) asked how the coefficients can be plotted in `coefplot` in descending order. The answer was to include `sort = 'magnitude'`

However, I then discovered that this method does not work when plotting multiple models using `multiplot`:

```
data(tips, package = "reshape2")
mod1 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker, data = tips)
mod2 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker + size, data = tips)
multiplot(mod1, mod2, decreasing = TRUE, sort = "magnitude")
```

Is there a way to do this with `multiplot`? I realize it might not be straightforward. I just wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: general question: how should sorting in decreasing order work when there's more than one model which might have different coefficient rank orders? Sort by coefficients of the first model?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do this with `coefplot()`, but I can offer a solution with the similar `dotwhisker` package:

Fit models:

```
data(tips, package = "reshape2")
mod1 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker, data = tips)
mod2 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker + size, data = tips)

library(dotwhisker)
## figure out order
ov <- names(sort(coef(mod2),decreasing=TRUE))
dwplot(list(mod1=mod1,mod2=mod2),order_vars=ov)+
    theme_bw()+
    geom_vline(xintercept=0,lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't checked, but are you saying (1) there's a bug in `dwplot()` so that the coefficients of mod1 aren't matched up right with the labels or (2) the label-matching is correct?  If the latter, then I don't see how it's logically possible to have *both* sorted and in the same plot.  `order(coef(mod1))` is `6 4 5 2 3 1`; `order(coef(mod2))` is `4 2 3 5 6 7 1` ... (This is the same issue as my comment above.)

Comment: Certainly not claiming there is a bug. If anything your second point is spot-on: there is a bug in my thinking that an ordered coefficient plot for two models is possible. In retrospect my question was pretty stupid.